# play multi-instrument MIDI file

Tags: ios, core-audio, coremidi

I have been working with the `MusicPlayer` and `MusicSequence` classes to play MIDI files. However, I am wondering how to specify instruments for different channels. What is the `MusicPlayer`'s default response to program change events? Can I tell the `MusicPlayer` to use certain samplers for certain channels? Or is the only way to set my own function as a MIDI Endpoint, and then handle the playing of notes myself using `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent()` to specify the sampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify different instruments for different tracks in a MusicSequence. ([MusicTrack API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicTrack_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009332)) I don't think MusicPlayer does anything with channels per se. You can specify that channels be converted to tracks when loading a MIDI file.

> Music Sequence Load Flags
>
> Flags used to configure the behavior of the MusicSequenceFileLoad and
>   MusicSequenceFileLoadData functions.
>
> enum {    kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks = (1 << 0) }; typedef
>   UInt32 MusicSequenceLoadFlags;
>
> Constants
>
> kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks
>
> ```
> If this flag is set the resultant Sequence will contain a tempo track, 1 track for each MIDI Channel that is found in the SMF, 1 track
> ```
>
> for SysEx or MetaEvents - and this will be the last track in the
>   sequence after the LoadSMFWithFlags calls.
>
> ```
> Available in OS X v10.3 and later.
>
> Declared in MusicPlayer.h.
> ```